# assigning on click or button to javascript function wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a function, with some unfamiliar code inside. This works, but I am trying to assign a button, or link to run this and normal javascript events will not work.  The app is based on jquery, and jqueryui.

```
el.prototype.commands.mkdir = function() {
    this.disableOnSearch = true;
    this.updateOnSelect = false;
    this.mime = 'directory';
    this.prefix = 'untitled folder';

    this.exec = $.proxy(this.fm.res('mixin', 'make'), this);

    this.shortcuts = [{
        pattern: 'ctrl+shift+n'}];

    this.getstate = function() {
        return !this._disabled && this.fm.cwd().write ? 0 : -1;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Have I put it in wrong. I am not sure on how to change format.

Comment: You're just showing what you're trying to run, not how you're trying to run it--we have no idea what happens, what's supposed to happen, how you're binding the event, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I was just using <input type="button" value="mkdir" id="mkdir">, and creating a function #mkdir with above code, and using <div id="mkfile" class="button">mkfile</div>

Comment: Are you using anything else besides jQuery or a particular jQueryUI plugin? Unless there's something that goes in and pulls this information out and does something with it, there's no event binding going on at all.

Comment: I think this is a jqueryui option. It mentions here. http://jqueryui.com/docs/Upgrade_Guide. It mentions  $.ui.foo.prototype.options, and I think they are calling plugins. However I dont know how to call them from a button. According to my script there is a plugin called mkfile, which I need to manually call. I think jqueryui uses this and then adds the relevant classes to an element. Any ideas. i.e it says uiOptions : {
  // toolbar configuration
  toolbar : [
   
   ['mkdir', 'mkfile', 'upload'],

Comment: It starts the script with foo.prototype._options = {

Answer (score 0):

The above is code from elFinder, which is open-source and can be found on github. elFinder has a function/button ready for you for the create folder action. What else are you trying to achieve?